# Заполнить элементы матрицы случайным образом целыми числами. Вывести элементы матрицы

Tags: python, массивы

Задания: Заполнить элементы матрицы случайным образом целыми числами. Вывести элементы матрицы.
Вывести номер столбцов, сумма элементов которых является крупнейшей

В питоне недавно, и язык не очень нравится но практические сдавать надо.

```
import random  

def creatArray():
    print('Input first index matrix: ')
    x = int(input())
    print('Input second index matrix: ')
    y = int(input())
    array = ([0]*x)*y
    for i in range (0,x-1):
        for j in range (0, y-1):
            array[i][j] = random.randint(0,100)
    return array

print(creatArray())
```

таким образом хотел заполнить массив, но выдает ошибку на строке 14 и 11
`'TypeError: 'int' object does not support item assignment`

Прошу объяснить в чем здесь проблема и помочь с решением с 3 заданиям (вывести номер столбцов...)

Comment: Укажите содержание проблемной строки

Answer (score 3):

Решение в стиле [Numpy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/user/quickstart.html):

```
In [9]: import numpy as np

In [10]: nrows = 10

In [11]: ncols = 8

In [12]: a = np.random.randint(100, size=(nrows,ncols))

In [13]: a
Out[13]:
array([[42, 18, 97, 96, 19, 98, 74,  1],
       [ 1, 23, 81, 83, 29, 41, 59, 57],
       [ 9, 11, 13, 37, 31, 54, 51, 38],
       [42, 14, 30, 91,  2, 89, 86, 70],
       [60, 87, 78, 63, 34, 29, 24, 82],
       [74, 61, 36, 26, 78, 28, 45, 36],
       [67, 31, 75,  8, 60, 14,  9, 76],
       [71, 60, 82, 55, 81, 89, 23, 42],
       [12, 76, 83, 11, 17, 54, 65, 50],
       [37, 63, 42, 79, 10, 32, 43, 53]])
```

сумма элементов в столбцах:

```
In [14]: a.sum(axis=0)
Out[14]: array([415, 444, 617, 549, 361, 528, 479, 505])
```

столбец с максимальной суммой элементов:

```
In [15]: a.sum(axis=0).argmax()
Out[15]: 2
```

сумма элементов в строках:

```
In [16]: a.sum(axis=1)
Out[16]: array([445, 374, 244, 424, 457, 384, 340, 503, 368, 359])
```

строка с максимальной суммой элементов:

```
In [17]: a.sum(axis=1).argmax()
Out[17]: 7
```

Comment: большое спасибо за ответ!

Answer (score 1):

`([0]*x)*y` - это не список списков, а просто список целых чисел: `[0] * x` разворачивается в список нулей, а потом `[0, ..., 0] * y` превращается в список из `x * y` нулей. Попытка обращения к нулю как к списку приводит к указанной ошибке.

Чтобы правильно создать список списков, состоящий полностью из нулей, можно воспользоваться генератором списка:

```
array = [[0] * x for _ in range(y)]
```

Также можно использовать двухуровневый генератор списка, чтобы сразу создать список списков со случайными числами:

```
array = [[random.randint(0, 100) for i in range(x)] for j in range(y)]
```

Кстати, т.к. `range(0, x-1)` дает числа от `0` до `x-2`, то у вас в массиве в последнем столбце и последней строке останутся нули. Чтобы работало правильно, должно быть `range(0, x)` или просто `range(x)`.

С остальным я бы посоветовал разобраться самостоятельно. Если уж совсем не получится, тогда задайте отдельный вопрос.

Comment: большое спасибо за ответ!

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо всем, но нашел другой вариант который подошел мне

```
import random  
def creatArray():
    r = 0
    print('Input first index matrix: ')
    x = int(input())
    print('Input second index matrix: ')
    y = int(input())
    array = []
    for i in range(x):
        array.append([])
        for j in range(y):
            array[i].append(random.randint(0,100))
            r += 1  
    return array
print(creatArray())
```